# How can you combine multiple async file uploads and be able to reference and write BOTH newly created URLS to database at same time?

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm working on this "postAPI" where the payload it takes in can contain up to (2) separate files.

Once the payload containing the files is dispatched to postAPI.  I need it to upload the files to a firebase storage bucket and then save/write the URLs after that is successful.

I can get it working now if I limit it to be either one file or the other with the code shown below.

My problem is if there are both files, I can't reference / pass the newly uploaded URL that gets returned to the second process. Here is some code to help explain.

Here is basically how I have it split up currently:

```
export function postAPI(payload) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true));

    if (payload.firstDoc !== "") {
      const upload = storage
        .ref(`documents/${payload.firstDoc.name}`)
        .put(payload.firstDoc);
      upload.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          console.log(`Progress: ${progress}%`);
          if (snapshot.state === "RUNNING") {
            console.log(`Progress: ${progress}%`);
          }
        },
        (error) => console.log(error.code),
        async () => {
          const downloadURL = await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
          db.collection("articles").add({
            data: payload.data,
            firstDoc: downloadURL,
            secondDoc: "",
          });
          dispatch(setLoading(false));
        }
      );
    } 

    if (payload.secondDoc !== "") {
        const secondUpload = storage
          .ref(`documents/${payload.secondDoc.name}`)
          .put(payload.secondDoc);
        secondUpload.on(
          "state_changed",
          (snapshot) => {
            const progress =
              (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  
            console.log(`Progress: ${progress}%`);
            if (snapshot.state === "RUNNING") {
              console.log(`Progress: ${progress}%`);
            }
          },
          (error) => console.log(error.code),
          async () => {
            const secondDownloadURL = await secondUpload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
            console.log(downloadURLpod);
            db.collection("articles").add({
                data: payload.data,
                firstDoc: "",
                secondDoc: secondDownloadURL,
            });
            dispatch(setLoading(false));
          }
        );
      }
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to store and/or pass the first 'downloadURL' to be available inside the second process.

Basically I just need a way to be able to have access to both downloadURL and secondDownloadURL simultaneously for the same db.add().

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the upload as `Promise` and not as upload task. That way you can simply await them until each of them finishes. It would look like this:

```js
export async function postAPI(payload) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true));

    let downloadURL1 = null;
    let downloadURL2 = null;

    if (payload.firstDoc !== "") {
      const snapshot1 = await storage
        .ref(`documents/${payload.firstDoc.name}`)
        .put(payload.firstDoc);

      const downloadURL1 = await snapshot1.ref.getDownloadURL();
    }

    if (payload.secondDoc !== "") {
      const snapshot2 = await storage
        .ref(`documents/${payload.secondDoc.name}`)
        .put(payload.secondDoc);

      const downloadURL2 = await snapshot2.ref.getDownloadURL();
    }

    db.collection("articles").add({
      data: payload.data,
      firstDoc: downloadURL1,
      secondDoc: downloadURL2,
    });
    dispatch(setLoading(false));
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! The only thing your example answer was really missing was making sure to wrap all the logic and everything inside an async(). I was able to figure that out pretty quickly and it's now working like I need it to!

Comment: Great to hear it :) I forget it often when copying other code and change it. Need to put more focus on this. Thx for letting me know.